# syntax error when deploying DBUP script through octtopus

Tags: sql, sql-server, octopus-deploy, dbup

I have DBUP scripts in the .Net Frameowrk4.5 project. For some reason when deploying the project through octopus, I get the below syntax error. This works ok on the local SQL server.

This is script

[image]

I get below error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it could be an encoding issue, is the language encoding of the embedded .sql file different than the OS language selection of the server?

Comment: I also suspect some encoding issues. The SQL was written by another developer from a different team. I have re-written the SQL on my PC and it works this time.